# CombineにRxSwiftのDisposeBagのような機能のものはありますか？

Tags: swift, rx-swift, combine

CombineにRxSwiftのDisposeBagのような機能のものはありますか？

下記のようなコードだと、Future呼び出しごとに `AnyCancellable`の変数を用意しないといけません。

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class Hoge {
    private var cancellable1: AnyCancellable?
    private var cancellable2: AnyCancellable?
    
    func foo() {
        self.cancellable1 = createFuture().sink(
            receiveValue: { v in
                print(v)
            }
        )
        self.cancellable2 = createFuture().sink(
            receiveValue: { v in
                print(v)
            }
        )
    }
    
    private func createFuture() -> Future<Int, Never> {
      return Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            promise(.success(10))
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[store(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable/store(in:)-6cr9i)が使えます。
`store(in:)`に与える `Set<AnyCancellable>` も用意しましょう。
（この `Set<AnyCancellable>`が`DisposeBag`のようなものに当たります）

下記のコードのように使います。

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class Hoge {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func foo() {
        self.createFuture().sink(
            receiveValue: { v in
                print(v)
            }
        ).store(in: &self.cancellables)
        self.createFuture().sink(
            receiveValue: { v in
                print(v)
            }
        ).store(in: &self.cancellables)

    }
    
    private func createFuture() -> Future<Int, Never> {
      return Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            promise(.success(10))
        }
      }
    }
}
```